# formula for a sphere?

Tags: analytic-geometry

is there such a thing as a formula for a sphere? Is it $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$? 
if so, does the $1$ denotes a radius of $1$ for said sphere? what are the possible alterations for such a formula?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: It might be better to check [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere) first.

Comment: Do you know how to find the distance between two points in 3D? (Specifically, between the origin and the point $(x,y,z)$.) Pythagoras tells us that, in 2D, we have $\text{distance}^2=x^2+y^2$. Use this to find and prove the formula for 3D.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general $(x-x_0)^2 + (y-y_0)^2 + (z-z_0)^2 = R^2$ represents a sphere centered in $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ with radius $R$

It is important to understand what this actually means: It means that if you take the set of all the real numbers  $x, y, z$ such that the above equation is satisfied, and you plot them, you'll end up with a sphere.
Note that a priori there is no easy way to find which points actually satisfy the equation.

---

You may wonder why we represent a sphere in such a convoluted way, while for example a line is simply $y = mx$ and you plug whatever value of $x$ you choose and you know the value of $y$, without need to make too much calculations. 
The problem is that a sphere is *not* a function (much like a circle on the plane) so we need to give this "implicit" representation.

However you can give explicit representation for just *part* of the sphere. The relevant theorem here is [Dini's theorem for implicit function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem)